# useState hook not working with usePrevious hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a menu component and I'm trying to use the useState hook to store which sub-menus are open. When the menu is closed (from the parent using props) I want to close all sub-menus and to do this I've using the usePrevious hook from the react-hanger library to determine when the main menu is going from OPEN > CLOSED . Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { usePrevious } from "react-hanger"

const defaultMenusOpen = {menu1:false, menu2:false}

function Menu(props) {

    const [subMenusOpen, setSubMenusOpen] = useState(defaultMenusOpen))
    const prevIsOpen = usePrevious(props.isOpen);


    if(props.isOpen === false && prevIsOpen === true){
        setSubMenusOpen(defaultMenusOpen)
    }

    return (
        {props.isOpen && 
            ... JSX
        }
    );

}

export default Menu
```

The problem is that this is causing an infinite loop error and continually re-rendering the Menu.

This seems to be because he if statement if TRUE on every re-render because calling setSubMenusOpen doesn't seem to cause usePrevious to store the new value again. This is what I think is happening.

- props.isOpen changes from TRUE > FALSE
- prevIsOpen and props.isOpen are TRUE and FALSE at this point, so...
- setSubMenusOpen() is called which causes a re-render.
- Instead of previsOpen and props.isOpen now being FALSE and FALSE, they remain unchanged, so setSubMenusOpen gets called again, ad finitum

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you are setting state directly in render which is causing an infinite cycle of setting state and re-rendering. Instead use the `useEffect` hook and execute it only on `isOpen` prop change

```
function Menu(props) {

    const [subMenusOpen, setSubMenusOpen] = useState(defaultMenusOpen))
    const prevIsOpen = usePrevious(props.isOpen);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.isOpen === false && prevIsOpen === true){
            setSubMenusOpen(defaultMenusOpen)
        }
    }, [props.isOpen])


    return (
        {props.isOpen && 
            ... JSX
        }
    );

}

export default Menu
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try that out tonight. The hardest thing about moving to functional compobents/hooks is understanding the lifecycle. As a novice it looks like the code inside useEffect would only be run once when the component is mounted, not every time the props change.

Comment: Hang on a sec, if useEffect() is the equivalent of componentDidMount() and componentDidUnmount() then what is the equivalent of componentDidUpdate()?

Comment: useEffect is not an equivalent of componentDidMount, it can be used to replicate behaviours or componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, componentWillUnmount

Comment: The second parameter to useEffect is what determines when this effect will be executed. If no second parameter is defined, it executes on every render, it an empty array is specified it executes callback after the initial render, if values are values in array, then it checks if there is change in any of those values and then decides whether to invoke callback or not

Comment: Thanks, so basically it runs on mount and every subsequent render but you can tell it to re-render only when the supplied props change. The only thing missing I guess is the ability to decide whether to render or not based on some other kind of logic.